QGIS - collect geometries with geometrygenerator by value to display only one label
I have a layer "vIAN_py" that displays areas of roads, that have previously been divided by parcels. the roads may have different names, but since they have been divided to many labels appear, if i want to display the names. Is there a way to only display one label for every road, f.e. by collecting or aggregating them with the geometrygenerator by the value of the attribute "name" from the vIAN_py Layer?

By "that displays areas of roads" you mean that you have polygon feature right ? (if you are using line feature there a setting to "Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels")

'Merge connected lines to avoid duplicate labels' is the best option for lines. Another expression you can use for the "show labels" data-defined override is $id = array_agg($id,"name")[0] though this can be slow for large datasets.

If your road are polygon feature you may use the expression :
buffer (collect ($geometry,"name" ),0)

in the geometry generator to get one polygon for feature with the same name
